# OpenConnect config using .pfx file on Debian

Tags: openvpn

I'm moving from physical servers running Debian Jessie using Cisco 5505/6 ASA boxes to create a VPN to a Cisco at the far end to Google Compute running Jessie. As I can't use physical VPN clients I need a s/w solution and believe OpenConnect is the way to go.

However.... Documentation is basic and I can't get it to connect. So, how do I configure OpenConnect to use a .pfx file?

(edit - changed from OpenVPN to OpenConnect. Been trying various but OpenConnect has been recommended by the far end provider)

Answer (score 2):

`.pfx` or `.p12` files are in PKCS#12 format; they're a bundle of certificates and private keys. Meanwhile, OpenConnect wants the certificate in plain PEM format.

Use GnuTLS or OpenSSL tools to convert from one format to other:

```
certtool --inraw --p12-info < client.p12 > client.pem
```

```
openssl pkcs12 -in client.p12 -out client.pem
```

The same output file should be suitable for both `--certificate` and `--sslkey` options in OpenConnect, but you can also separate it into two `.crt` and `.key` files with a text editor.

Comment: Thanks, that just times out:  
`openconnect -c client.pem 1.2.3.4`
`POST https://1.2.3.4/`
`Attempting to connect to server 1.2.3.4:443`
`Failed to connect to host 1.2.3.4`
`Failed to open HTTPS connection to 1.2.3.4`
`GET https://1.2.3.4/`
`Attempting to connect to server 1.2.3.4`
`Failed to connect to host 1.2.3.4`
`Failed to open HTTPS connection to 1.2.3.4`
`Failed to obtain WebVPN cookie`

Comment: Well that's definitely not a certificate problem. Are you sure the server is configured for AnyConnect/Openconnect, and not for the older IPSec VPN (vpnc)?

Comment: OK, sorted. I think the main problem was that I was using the wrong url..... Thanks for your help.